# MYSQL Match AGAINST

Tags: mysql, indexing, match

I have table called 'business' with 13,000,000 records so far.
I want to search in this table on lowerTitle and phone fields.
If I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM business WHERE MATCH (lowerTitle) AGAINST (`blabla` IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It's working fast, Now I want to search also in `phone` field using:

```
SELECT * FROM business WHERE MATCH (lowerTitle,phone) AGAINST (`blabla` IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

for some reason, it's working very slow, someone can assist here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Who us output of `SHOW INDEX FROM business`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you've a **full text** (not btree) index on (lowerTitle,phone). If not:

```
create fulltext index business_ft_idx on business(lowerTitle, phone);
```

Comment: `lowerTitle` and `phone` are fulltexts. should I do a index for both? and if later I will have to search in other fields like state, country, city etc'?

Comment: Yeah, you need a multi-column index. MySQL doesn't know how to do a bitmap index scan. Chances are it knows how to use any of the columns in a fulltext index query when you match against the individual fields (much like gist indexes in postgres), though, so you'll probably be able to get rid of the full text indexes on the individual columns. (try it.)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON business (lowerTitle, phone)' at line 1